# ElasticSearch Script Field Returns Incorrect Longitude Value

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, elasticsearch

When I add:

```
fields: [ "doc['Location'].lon" ]
```

to my query, the longitude value is different that what is shown in the document source.

Here you can see the results of a query where I fetched the doc['Latitude'].lon and .lat, and the _source.Latitude to compare:

https://gist.github.com/d9533170f1f50fd27e87 (note - these have been passed through json_decode in PHP, but the data is the same before using json_decode.)

I first noticed this when I was using "doc['field_name'].distance(lat, lon)" to try and add the distance as a field to my query. I tried both the "script_fields" and "fields" keys and each had the same result.

UPDATE: I noticed that the "doc['Location'].lon" is returning what I thought should be the doc['Location'].lat (the lat and lon are switched.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that when using GeoJSON format (or using lat/long as an array) you have to [switch the order of lat/lng to lng/lat](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html).

I am rebuilding my index, but, in order to work around this I have used this query for now:

```
doc['Location'].distance( lon + 180, lat ) // Temporary bandaid
```

Once I've rebuilt the index with the correct values I'll switch back to:

```
doc['field_name'].distance(lat, lon) // The correct method
```

Comment: David, yeah unfortunately this is a common problem when working with Spatial data. x,y != y,x and a lot of people here in the US often relate x to latitude.